# Do doors slow dwarves down?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Say I had a corridor that was entirely filled with doors, would opening the doors to go through them slow my dwarves down?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Opening the door is "free" with the cost of moving into the square.